# MariaDB database has no 'max_used_connections'

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, debian

I have a running MariaDB which has no `max_used_connections` variable. How can I see it?

I got the list of all variables using the following command from the shell:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

but it was not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Max_used_connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#max_used_connections) is a status variable, not a system variable, so therefore the incantation to show its value is:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Comment: See also `Max_used_connections_time`